# Static ResourceBundle

Tags: java, static, resources, resourcebundle

I am currently making resources for an app that is using ResourceBundle. The thing is, with the current code to dispatch the resources I would need to create an instance of the resource bundle every time I need it and I can guess this is not a good idea, since I would end up loading the resources again and again.

The second solution would be to divide the bundle into many, But I would end up with bundles have only 2-3 strings and like 15 bundles.

**My question is:**
Is there a way to simple load all the resources in a single static class and access them from there.

I made this little piece of code that seems to work for me but I doubt its quality.

```
public class StaticBundle
{
    private final static ResourceBundle resBundle = 
        ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.resources");
    public final static String STRING_A = resBundle.getString("KEY_A");
    public final static String STRING_B = resBundle.getString("KEY_B");
    public final static String STRING_C = resBundle.getString("KEY_C");
}
```

With this I can call `StaticBundle.STRING_A` and get the value anywhere in the project but since the bundle is initialized at the same time as the class itself... It is highly possible that the program won't have the time to load the proper local from the preferences.

Is there a good way to do this or any other possible solution?

Thank you

Comment: What you have is fine, if you'll only use the default locale to load your keys. But don't worry too much about performance: `ResourceBundle.getBundle()` uses a cache, and doesn't reload the resources each time it's called.

Answer (score 4):

If you intend to have only messages for the default locale then what you have is fine.

Alternatively you could let the caller specify which key it needs instead of having constants, like this:

```
public static String getMessage(String key) {
    return resBundle.getString(key);
}
```

If you like to support multiple locales then the usual approach is to have a <strike>`Map<Locale, ResourceBundle>`</strike>`Map<Locale, Map<String, String>` where you load the resources only once for each locale. In that case your class would have a method where the caller can specify the locale:

```
public static String getMessage(String key, Locale locale) {
    Map<String, String> bundle = bundles.get(locale);   // this is the map with all bundles
    if (bundle == null) {
        // load the bundle for the locale specified
        // here you would also need some logic to mark bundles that were not found so
        // to avoid continously searching bundles that are not present 

        // you could even return the message for the default locale if desirable
    }
    return bundle.get(key);
}
```

**Edit:** As correctly pointed out by @JB Nizet (thanks) `ResourceBundle` already stores a `Map`. The custom solution I provided in the source example,  was about a custom mechanism similar to `ResourceBundle` that used a `Map` of `Map`s to load translations of keys in a property=value format, not only from files but also a database. I have incorrectly thought that we had a `Map` of `ResourceBundle` in that solution. The source example is fixed now.

Comment: In fact I change the default local for the run-time at the very beginning so I don't need to fetch the local every time I need the resources (I'm a bit lazy). So your second solution wont do for me, I like the idea tho. Finaly, I made constant to centralize where I need to change the Resources Key if they were to change (again my laziness).

Comment: There is no point in storing the bundles in a map. `ResourceBundle.getBundle()` does that already, and does it right, in a thread-safe way.

Comment: @JBNizet you are right of course. We had a custom solution in a project, were we used `Map<Locale, Map<String, String>>` for a custom solution. My memory betrayed me and thought we had a `Map<Locale, ResourceBundle>`. I have edited my answer to correct this. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

You can create a singleton class:

```
public class MyResouceBundle extends ResourceBundle {

    private static MyResourceBundle instance = new MyResouceBundle();

    // private constructor, no one can instantiate this class, only itself
    private MyResourceBundle() {

    }

    public ResourceBundle getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Then, everyone will access the same instance of the class with (to get string for KEY_A, for example):

```
MyResourceBunde.getInstance().get("KEY_A");
```